# Expand variable inside single quotes

Tags: powershell, variable-expansion

How can I expand `$pw` inside single quotes?

```
$pw = "$PsHome\powershell.exe"
cmd.exe /c 'schtasks /create /tn cleanup /tr "$pw -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile %TEMP%\exec.ps1" /sc minute /mo 1'
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use formatting and assign it to another variable:

```
$pw = "$PsHome\powershell.exe";
$command = 'schtasks /create /tn cleanup /tr "{0} -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile %TEMP%\exec.ps1" /sc minute /mo 1' -f $pw;
cmd.exe /c $command
```

Or you can use double quotes and escape the inside quotes with quotes:

```
$pw = "$PsHome\powershell.exe"
cmd.exe /c "schtasks /create /tn cleanup /tr ""$pw -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile %TEMP%\exec.ps1"" /sc minute /mo 1"
```

Or do the same but use backtick (grave) to escape them:

```
$pw = "$PsHome\powershell.exe"
cmd.exe /c "schtasks /create /tn cleanup /tr `"$pw -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile %TEMP%\exec.ps1`" /sc minute /mo 1"
```

Comment: You rock @bacon-bits , all your solutions work, tks!

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to use the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$ExecutionContext`:

```
$pw = "$PsHome\powershell.exe"
$cmd = 'schtasks /create /tn cleanup /tr "$pw -WindowStyle hidden -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -nologo -noprofile %TEMP%\exec.ps1" /sc minute /mo 1'
$cmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($cmd)
cmd.exe /c $cmd
```