# Adding dollar sign in front of variable name in arguments of Powershell script

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, pipeline, azure-powershell, dollar-sign

I am working on pipeline where I am passing arguments in the powershell script as below. I want to append ServiceName and Environment.Name with a $ sign.

> arguments: '-ServiceDisplayName "$(ServiceDisplayName)" -ServiceName
> "$(ServiceName)$(Environment.Name)" -ServiceDirectory
> "$(ServiceFolder)" -UserName "$(ServiceUserAccount)"'

Tried -ServiceName "$(ServiceName)`$$(Environment.Name)"

Comment: They can't be within single quotes.

Comment: use backtick (grave) to escape them. Go through [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127583/expand-variable-inside-single-quotes)

Comment: @RanadipDutta tried this  -ServiceName "$(ServiceName)`$$(Environment.Name)" doesn't work

Comment: I guess what you want is `-ServiceDisplayName $ServiceDisplayName -ServiceName "$ServiceName$($Environment.Name)" -ServiceDirectory $ServiceFolder -UserName $ServiceUserAccount`. Note that you have to write a valid expression within `$(…)`, the sub-expression operator, so insert another `$` to reference a variable. Neither sub-expression nor quoting are necessary to pass a single variable.

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes.  Single quotes will not replace the dollar sign with a variable.