# Unable to execute maven mvn command having whitespace in absolute path using GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: powershell, maven, github-actions

I install maven `mvn` on the fly on Windows which is a GitHub runner that uses Powershell.

I then wish to run and execute the installed maven.

Below are my workflow attempts which do not work and get me the following errors:

```yaml
    - name: Set up Maven
      id: setup-mvn       
      run: |
        $mavenHome = "C:\Program Files\apache-maven"
        echo "setmavenhome=$mavenHome" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"

    - name: Print Maven version
      run: |
        #$mavenHome = "C:\Temp Files\apache-maven"

        #Attempt 1
        echo "${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}"
        & "${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}\bin\mvn" -version
        pause     

        #Attempt 2
        '${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}\bin\mvn' -version

        #Attempt 3
        $mvnCmd = "'${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}\bin\mvn' -f `"${{ steps.checkout-path.outputs.repopath }}\$relativePath`" $target"
        $mvnOutput = Invoke-Expression $mvnCmd
      shell: powershell
```

- Output of Attempt 1 where the version does not get printed:

  ```
  C:\Temp Files\apache-maven

  Press Enter to continue...:
  ```
- Output of Attempt 2:

  ```
  At D:\Git-Runners\selfhosted-s1\_work\_temp\292129f7-f9bf-41a5-a429-84e417e2efc6.ps1:7 char:47
  + 'C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.3\bin\mvn' -version
  +                                               ~~~~~~~~
  Unexpected token '-version' in expression or statement.
      + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
  ```
- Output of Attempt 3: Similar error as in Attempt 2

I need a solution for all the three attempts.

Can you please suggest?

Comment: Did you try [adding it to system path](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=powershell#adding-a-system-path) instead? After adding it to system path, you won't have to use the output parameter. You can simply use `mvn` as any other command.

Comment: Observe the difference in quotes in this line `echo “${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}"`. That must be the issue you've been facing. Check this relevant thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246735/unexpected-token-errors-in-powershell.

Comment: @Azeem `echo “` is due to copy paste issue ... i do have the correct quotes where is it failing. I did not try adding to the system path. Let me try it.

Comment: Right. Sure, adding its absolute `bin` path to system path seems to be a better solution in this case. Regarding your existing workflow, you need to share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That'll be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better solution would be to add the absolute path of `mvn` directory to the system path using `GITHUB_PATH` in a separate step:

```
"{path}" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Append
```

and, then you can use `mvn` as any other command in the subsequent steps.

See [Adding a System Path](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=powershell#adding-a-system-path) in Powershell for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem... Can you please check unanswered query here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77559403/loss-of-indentation-and-formatting-occurs-when-saving-the-output-to-a-file-and-r?noredirect=1#comment136734190_77559403

Comment: @Ashar: Sure, no problem. I looked at that post but it's about Ansible and I'm not well-versed in it. Apparently, looks like that the output JSON being dumped is being treated as a nested string literal and that's why everything in it is escaped. See if you can use [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) here to process the JSON.

Answer (score 3):

In your attempt 1, you are trying to execute the Maven command with the absolute path, which includes whitespace.
In PowerShell, you should enclose the path in quotes, and use the [call operator `&`](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) to execute it.

```yaml
- name: Print Maven version
  run: |
    & "${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}\bin\mvn" -version
  shell: powershell
```

For attempt 2, the issue is with the single quotes `'`. [PowerShell does not expand variables inside single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32127583/6309). Use double quotes or no quotes at all if the path does not contain spaces.

```yaml
- name: Print Maven version
  run: |
    & "${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}\bin\mvn" -version
  shell: powershell
```

And in attempt 3, the problem is similar to attempt 2, but you are also trying to use `Invoke-Expression`, which requires the command to be a single string. Make sure to properly quote the paths and arguments.

```yaml
- name: Execute Maven Command
  run: |
    $mvnCmd = "& `"$(${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}\bin\mvn)`" -f `"$(${{ steps.checkout-path.outputs.repopath }}\$relativePath)`" $target"
    $mvnOutput = Invoke-Expression $mvnCmd
  shell: powershell
```

Do adjust the `$relativePath` and `$target` variables as needed.

---

> Isn't your `Attempt 1` same as in the OP's description?

The GitHub Actions syntax `${{...}}` is indeed expanded before the script is executed, so the original method should work.
However, if it is not working, one reason could be the way GitHub Actions handles the output variables.

Let's try a slightly modified approach:

```yaml
- name: Print Maven version
  run: |
    & "$env:MAVEN_HOME\bin\mvn" -version
  env:
    MAVEN_HOME: ${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}
  shell: powershell
```

Here, we use an environment variable `MAVEN_HOME` to store and access the Maven path.

---

> Regarding your explanation of `Attempt 2`, it doesn't apply here as it's not a PowerShell variable.
> The expression `${{...}}` should expand in single quotes also

The `${{...}}` syntax is evaluated by GitHub Actions before the script runs, so it should correctly expand in single quotes in YAML. The issue might be the use of single quotes in the PowerShell script, which do not expand PowerShell variables. Since `${{...}}` is not a PowerShell variable but a GitHub Actions expression, it should be expanded correctly.

```yaml
- name: Print Maven version
  run: |
    & '${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}\bin\mvn' -version
  shell: powershell
```

.

---

Attempt 3 adjustment:

In this attempt, the key is to make sure the entire command is a single string when using `Invoke-Expression`.
The GitHub Actions variables will be expanded before the PowerShell script runs. Make sure the command is properly quoted and concatenated.

```yaml
- name: Execute Maven Command
  run: |
    $mvnCmd = "& '${{ steps.setup-mvn.outputs.setmavenhome }}\bin\mvn' -f '${{ steps.checkout-path.outputs.repopath }}\$relativePath' $target"
    $mvnOutput = Invoke-Expression $mvnCmd
  shell: powershell
```

Comment: HI! Isn't your **Attempt 1** same as in the OP's description? Regarding your explanation of **Attempt 2**, it doesn't apply here as it's not a PowerShell variable. The expression `${{...}}` should expand in single quotes also.

Comment: @Azeem True. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: @Azeem GITHUB_PATH is the best solution... Thank you for the pointer